# Notice: Undefined variable but I already defined it

Tags: php, forms, variables, undefined

I'm having a problem and I can't find a solution. I'm getting this error "Notice: Undefined variable: id_horaire". But I defined it and I don't know how to fix that.
Here's my code :

```
<?php 
    require_once '../database.php';
    if (!$_SESSION['admin']) {
        header('location:login.php');
        exit();
    }
        
    if(isset($_GET['id']) AND !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id_horaireSecure = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
        $id_horaire = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM runaway.horaire WHERE id = ?');
        $id_horaire->execute(array($id_horaireSecure));
    }
        
        if(!empty($_POST['heure_ouverture']) AND !empty($_POST['heure_fermeture'])) {
            $heure_ouverture = ($_POST['heure_ouverture']);
            $heure_fermeture = ($_POST['heure_fermeture']);
            $update = $db->prepare('UPDATE runaway.horaire SET heureOuverture=?, heureFermeture=?');
            $update->execute(array($heure_ouverture, $heure_fermeture));
            $message = "L'horaire a bien été mise à jour";
            header('location:login.php');
            exit();
            } else {
            $message = 'Les champs ne sont pas tous remplis';
            }
        
?>
<div class="phpContainer">
        <h2>Changer les horaires d'ouverture du Lundi</h2>
        <div class="form col-12">
            <div class="contact-form container">
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="heure_ouverture" class="input" value="<?=$id_horaire['heureOuverture'] ?>" />
                        <label for="">Heure d'ouverture</label>
                        <span>Heure d'ouverture</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="heure_fermeture" class="input" value="<?=$id_horaire['heureFermeture'] ?>" />
                        <label for="">Heure de fermeture</label>
                        <span>Heure de fermeture</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Modifier l'horaire" class="boutonForm">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <?php if(isset($message)) {
            echo $message;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Thank you !
ps: I'm french, which is why some variables and text may seem strange to you

Comment: You have an condition before you set `$id_horraire`, which means that if you get an undefined error, the condition was false. Check that `$_GET['id']` exists and contains something.

Comment: I do have something in 'id' so I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you declare `$id_horaire` only if this condition `isset($_GET['id']) AND !empty($_GET['id'])` met.

You can either give it a default value before the if, or you need to change your logic.

Comment: I declared it before the it with a default value but now I'm getting these errors "Warning: Illegal string offset 'heureOuverture'", "Warning: Illegal string offset 'heureFermeture'"

Comment: @Cigixx Well clearly you've defined a string as a default value. What do you think `['heureFermeture']` should return on a string? You have a conditional variable, so you should check for its existence before using it. Also, you never actually fetch the result of your select, you try to use array access directly on the statement object. I think it's time for you to revisit the database tutorials.